# White text instead of Black text?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I could make my text on my paragraph and headings white, since the default is black. 
I really need the text to  be readable with my dark background.

```css
body {
  background-color: #101010;
}
#section {
  max-width: 960px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.main-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: left;
}
IMG.displayed {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
}
h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
div.wrapper {
  margin: 10px left;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}
nav.vertical {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
nav.vertical > ul {
  padding: 0;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label,
nav.vertical > ul > li > a {
  background: rgb(181, 189, 200);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(181, 189, 200) 0%, rgb(130, 140, 149) 36%, rgb(40, 52, 59) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(181, 189, 200) 0%, rgb(130, 140, 149) 36%, rgb(40, 52, 59) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(181, 189, 200) 0%, rgb(130, 140, 149) 36%, rgb(40, 52, 59) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  font-size: .85rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label:hover,
nav.vertical > ul > li > a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(114, 51, 98);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label + input {
  display: none;
  visability: hidden;
}
/* unvisited link */

a:link {
  color: #AAAAFF;
}
/* visited link */

a:visited {
  color: #DD04FF;
}
/* mouse over link */

a:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
}
/* selected link */

a:active {
  color: #FFCC00;
}
footer {
  color: #ffffff;
}
nav {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  border: 5px solid #333;
}
nav ul {
  nav ul: list-style-type: none;
}
nav li {
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
nav li a:link {
  text-decoration: none: font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
iv>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="vertical">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="homePage.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="profile.html">Profile</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="personalBests.html">Personal Bests</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="links.html">Links</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact.html">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id "section">
  <article>
    <h2>This is the section</h2>
    <p>
      Hello there, and welcome to FireFalcons personal website!
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent pharetra rutrum massa vitae cursus. Integer condimentum sollicitudin tristique. Ut lectus mi, iaculis eget faucibus quis, tincidunt eu ligula. Aliquam id ornare dui. Nulla efficitur ipsum
      vitae magna ultricies placerat ullamcorper ut turpis. Ut sed malesuada nibh. Phasellus fringilla ex a eros volutpat consectetur.
    </p>
  </article>
</div>
<hr>
<footer>
  <strong>
                    Copyright &copy; 2016 Stephen Fawcett, All rights reserved
            </strong>
</footer>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a typo `<div id "section">` needs to be `<div id="section">`